# Auth libraries for Ruby on Rails or JRuby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, jruby

I am thinking about implementing authentication and user management using Ruby (or jRuby since I have not decided between the two at the time of this writing).

What are some good auth libraries available for Ruby/jRuby? 
Also since I am sort of a Ruby-newb, can I potentially use the same library for either ruby or jruby?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at

http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication.html

for a list of authentication solutions for Rails, ranked by popularity.

Devise is the most popular. Here's a useful tutorial and example app that shows how to set up Devise:

[rails3-mongoid-devise tutorial and example](https://github.com/fortuity/rails3-mongoid-devise)

Comment: I concur with Daniel. Devise works well for me across both MRI Ruby and JRuby in 1.8 and 1.9 compatibility modes.

Answer (score 5):

Sorcery is another auth lib, which was born a few months ago, authored by me.

https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery

It is not so much for newbies, but it gives much more flexibility since it is a bare-bones API instead of a complete MVC solution.

Not yet tried on jruby.

See tutorials in the github wiki.